How do I run springboot app that serves react production build on an external tomcat without pom.xml and maven?
Due to my company restrictions, I am unable to use pom.xml and maven. Hence, I manually added the necessary jars into the application and application is serving the react production build with embedded tomcat. To deploy the application onto external tomcat, I have overriden configure() and created a simple web.xml
App.java
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class })
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAsync
public class App extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    
    
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(App.class);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);  
    }
    
    ...
}

web.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee" xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_6_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="6.0">
  <display-name>Test</display-name>
  
</web-app>

However, I am getting below JNDI context errors on running the application with "run on server". There are plenty more errors like Name [spring.aop.proxy-target-class] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [spring.aop.proxy-target-class] in the debug console.
Aug 07, 2024 10:05:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: 2 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
22:05:36,865 |-WARN in Logger[org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate] - No appenders present in context [default] for logger [org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate].
22:05:36,910 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.TimestampModelHandler - Using current interpretation time, i.e. now, as time reference.
22:05:36,910 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.TimestampModelHandler - Adding property to the context with key="myTimestamp" and value="2024-08-07" to the LOCAL scope
22:05:36,911 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.AppenderModelHandler - Processing appender named [FILE-THREAD]
22:05:36,911 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.AppenderModelHandler - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.SiftingAppender]
22:05:36,912 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.ImplicitModelHandler - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.MDCBasedDiscriminator] for [discriminator] property
22:05:36,912 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.AppenderModelHandler - Processing appender named [STDOUT]
22:05:36,912 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.AppenderModelHandler - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
22:05:36,914 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender[STDOUT] - This appender no longer admits a layout as a sub-component, set an encoder instead.
22:05:36,914 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender[STDOUT] - To ensure compatibility, wrapping your layout in LayoutWrappingEncoder.
22:05:36,914 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender[STDOUT] - See also http://logback.qos.ch/codes.html#layoutInsteadOfEncoder for details
22:05:36,914 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.model.processor.LoggerModelHandler - Setting level of logger [com.dcb.smsbatch] to DEBUG
22:05:36,915 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator@432e9de9 - Propagating DEBUG level on Logger[com.dcb.smsbatch] onto the JUL framework
22:05:36,920 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.model.processor.LoggerModelHandler - Setting additivity of logger [com.dcb.smsbatch] to false
22:05:36,920 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.AppenderRefModelHandler - Attaching appender named [FILE-THREAD] to Logger[com.dcb.smsbatch]
22:05:36,920 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.AppenderRefModelHandler - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[com.dcb.smsbatch]
22:05:36,920 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.model.processor.RootLoggerModelHandler - Setting level of ROOT logger to ERROR
22:05:36,920 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator@432e9de9 - Propagating ERROR level on Logger[ROOT] onto the JUL framework
22:05:36,920 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.AppenderRefModelHandler - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[ROOT]
22:05:36,920 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.DefaultProcessor@5299c25d - End of configuration.
22:05:36,920 |-INFO in org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.SpringBootJoranConfigurator@7541dbee - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point

[07-08-2024 - 22:05:36] [main] DEBUG JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/logging.register-shutdown-hook]
[07-08-2024 - 22:05:36] [main] DEBUG JndiLocatorDelegate - Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/logging.register-shutdown-hook] not found - trying original name [logging.register-shutdown-hook]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [logging.register-shutdown-hook] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [logging.register-shutdown-hook].
[07-08-2024 - 22:05:36] [main] DEBUG JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [logging.register-shutdown-hook]
[07-08-2024 - 22:05:36] [main] DEBUG JndiPropertySource - JNDI lookup for name [logging.register-shutdown-hook] threw NamingException with message: Name [logging.register-shutdown-hook] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [logging.register-shutdown-hook].. Returning null.
[07-08-2024 - 22:05:36] [main] DEBUG JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/context.listener.classes]
[07-08-2024 - 22:05:36] [main] DEBUG JndiLocatorDelegate - Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/context.listener.classes] not found - trying original name [context.listener.classes]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [context.listener.classes] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [context.listener.classes].
[07-08-2024 - 22:05:36] [main] DEBUG JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [context.listener.classes]
[07-08-2024 - 22:05:36] [main] DEBUG JndiPropertySource - JNDI lookup for name [context.listener.classes] threw NamingException with message: Name [context.listener.classes] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [context.listener.classes].. Returning null.
[07-08-2024 - 22:05:36] [main] DEBUG JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/spring.mandatory-file-encoding]
[07-08-2024 - 22:05:36] [main] DEBUG JndiLocatorDelegate - Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/spring.mandatory-file-encoding] not found - trying original name [spring.mandatory-file-encoding]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [spring.mandatory-file-encoding] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [spring.mandatory-file-encoding].
[07-08-2024 - 22:05:36] [main] DEBUG JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [spring.mandatory-file-encoding]
[07-08-2024 - 22:05:36] [main] DEBUG JndiPropertySource - JNDI lookup for name [spring.mandatory-file-encoding] threw NamingException with message: Name [spring.mandatory-file-encoding] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [spring.mandatory-file-encoding].. Returning null.
[07-08-2024 - 22:05:36] [main] DEBUG JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/spring.main.environment-prefix]
[07-08-2024 - 22:05:36] [main] DEBUG JndiLocatorDelegate - Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/spring.main.environment-prefix] not found - trying original name [spring.main.environment-prefix]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [spring.main.environment-prefix] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [spring.main.environment-prefix].
[07-08-2024 - 22:05:36] [main] DEBUG JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [spring.main.environment-prefix]
[07-08-2024 - 22:05:36] [main] DEBUG JndiPropertySource - JNDI lookup for name [spring.main.environment-prefix] threw NamingException with message: Name [spring.main.environment-prefix] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [spring.main.environment-prefix].. Returning null.
[07-08-2024 - 22:05:36] [main] DEBUG JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/spring.main]
[07-08-2024 - 22:05:36] [main] DEBUG JndiLocatorDelegate - Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/spring.main] not found - trying original name [spring.main]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [spring.main] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [spring.main].
[07-08-2024 - 22:05:36] [main] DEBUG JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [spring.main]
[07-08-2024 - 22:05:36] [main] DEBUG JndiPropertySource - JNDI lookup for name [spring.main] threw NamingException with message: Name [spring.main] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [spring.main].. Returning null.
[07-08-2024 - 22:05:37] [main] DEBUG JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/spring.banner.location]
[07-08-2024 - 22:05:37] [main] DEBUG JndiLocatorDelegate - Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/spring.banner.location] not found - trying original name [spring.banner.location]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [spring.banner.location] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [spring.banner.location].
[07-08-2024 - 22:05:37] [main] DEBUG JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [spring.banner.location]
[07-08-2024 - 22:05:37] [main] DEBUG JndiPropertySource - JNDI lookup for name [spring.banner.location] threw NamingException with message: Name [spring.banner.location] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [spring.banner.location].. Returning null.

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.1.2)

[07-08-2024 - 22:05:37] [main] DEBUG JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/context.initializer.classes]
[07-08-2024 - 22:05:37] [main] DEBUG JndiLocatorDelegate - Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/context.initializer.classes] not found - trying original name [context.initializer.classes]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [context.initializer.classes] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [context.initializer.classes].
[07-08-2024 - 22:05:37] [main] DEBUG JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [context.initializer.classes]
[07-08-2024 - 22:05:37] [main] DEBUG JndiPropertySource - JNDI lookup for name [context.initializer.classes] threw NamingException with message: Name [context.initializer.classes] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [context.initializer.classes].. Returning null.
[07-08-2024 - 22:05:37] [main] DEBUG JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/spring.application.name]
[07-08-2024 - 22:05:37] [main] DEBUG JndiLocatorDelegate - Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/spring.application.name] not found - trying original name [spring.application.name]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [spring.application.name] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [spring.application.name].
[07-08-2024 - 22:05:37] [main] DEBUG JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [spring.application.name]
[07-08-2024 - 22:05:37] [main] DEBUG JndiPropertySource - JNDI lookup for name [spring.application.name] threw NamingException with message: Name [spring.application.name] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [spring.application.name].. Returning null.
[07-08-2024 - 22:05:37] [main] DEBUG App - Running with Spring Boot v3.1.2, Spring v6.0.11
[07-08-2024 - 22:05:37] [main] DEBUG SpringApplication - Loading source class com.dcb.smsbatch.App,class org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilterConfiguration
[07-08-2024 - 22:05:37] [main] DEBUG AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@5549bf0
[07-08-2024 - 22:05:37] [main] DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor'
[07-08-2024 - 22:05:38] [main] DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.internalCachingMetadataReaderFactory'

I guess embedded tomcat might be using alot of JNDI configurations which aren't available in external tomcat but I am unable to think of a way to get all missing configurations into the application for external tomcat. Any help or suggestion for fixing this issue would be highly appreciated.

there are a bunch of debug messages, but not error per se... I'm going to venture that if your application is not running, these messages are a red herring- these properties can't be sourced from JNDI, so they are sourced from some other property source.

Lift the restrictions. Why on earth is that in place, searching the internet for a combination of jars that sort of work together is not something that you should do it will only lead to issues. The same for generating your deployable artifact.

To fix your issue, you need to build the application as a WAR.
To do so, please follow the official instructions here. The entire page is important, but please focus on the Deploying a WAR to Weblogic section (even if you're not using Weblogic).
On a side note, you can configure your maven to use offline repository (it might be a solution to your company's restriction). I personally recommend this option, but it depends on why your company is restricting maven usage in the first place :)
In effect, it's similar to adding dependencies manually, but with the better option of still using Maven.
Note that Gradle is not good at using offline dependencies. It can be done, but a bit hectic to setup compared to Maven
To do so:

Assuming you have maven project with default hierarchy, add the following folders to it:

root
|-.mvn
  |- repository
  |- settings.xml


In settings.xml file, add the following contents:

  <localRepository>.mvn/repository</localRepository>
  <offline>true</offline>


Run maven command specifying your settings.xml file using this command:

mvn -s .mvn/settings.xml install

I recommend the following readings:

https://www.baeldung.com/maven-settings-xml
How do I configure Maven for offline development?
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/go-offline-mojo.html
https://www.baeldung.com/maven-offline

